# How to save multiple checkbox on update post meta in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having multiple check boxes and I want to save the check box and also update it in the update_post_meta so that next time when a user edit the post, he would know which check boxes are already checked. I don't know where am I getting wrong. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box' );

 function add_custom_box( $post ) {

    add_meta_box(
            'Meta Box', // ID, should be a string
            'Music', // Meta Box Title
            'music_meta_box', // Your call back function, this is where your form field will go
            'post', // The post type you want this to show up on, can be post, page, or custom post type
            'side', // The placement of your meta box, can be normal or side
            'core' // The priority in which this will be displayed
        );

}

function music_meta_box( $post ) {

    // Get post meta value using the key from our save function in the second paramater.
    $custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom-meta-box', true);
?>

<input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="huge" <?php if(isset($_POST['custom-meta-box']['huge'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>  /> Huge <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="house" <?php if(isset($_POST['custom-meta-box']['house'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>  /> House <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="techno" <?php if(isset($_POST['custom-meta-box']['techno'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /> Techno <br>

<?php   


}
 add_action( 'save_post', 'save_music_meta_box' );

function save_music_meta_box(){

    global $post;

    // Get our form field
    if(isset( $_POST['custom-meta-box'] )) :

        $custom = $_POST['custom-meta-box'];

         // Update post meta

         foreach($ids as $id){
          update_post_meta($id, '_custom-meta-box', $custom[$id]);
         wp_set_object_terms( $id,  $custom[$id], 'Music' );
         }

    endif;

}
```

Please Help

Comment: why not serialize posted array, then updating it by creating single meta??

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Use the good ol' WP function `maybe_serialize()`, see here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize

Comment: @user3293145 Dear, we are here to solve your problem, not for doing tasks for you

Comment: LOL I'm sorry but I've no knowledge about serialize thats why I asked you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this logic:-

```
function music_meta_box( $post )
{
    // Get post meta value using the key from our save function in the second paramater.
    $custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);

    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="huge" <?php echo (in_array('huge', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Huge
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="house" <?php echo (in_array('house', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />House
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="techno" <?php echo (in_array('techno', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Techno<br>
    <?php 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_music_meta_box' );
function save_music_meta_box()
{

    global $post;
    // Get our form field
    if(isset( $_POST['custom-meta-box'] ))
    {
        $custom = $_POST['custom-meta-box'];
        $old_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);
        // Update post meta
        if(!empty($old_meta)){
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom);
        } else {
            add_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Why does "custom-meta-box[]" change to "_custom-meta-box" when updating the meta. What does the underscore do?

Comment: Because, there are multiple checkboxes, so `custom-meta-box[]` represent array. If you use `_custom-meta-box`, you will get only one option instead of multiple options.

Comment: `$custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);` this won't return an array, how is it used inside `in_array()`?

Comment: If you not checked any checkbox then empty value will be store, in that case you will not get any value, but if any checkbox is checked than you will find return value as an array.