# Save multiple checkbox on update post meta in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, custom-post-type

I have the same problem resolved in:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660822/how-to-save-multiple-checkbox-on-update-post-meta-in-wordpress](http://How%20to%20save%20multiple%20checkbox%20on%20update%20post%20meta%20in%20wordpress?)

I have a cpt (clinica) with a multiple checkbox metabox.

I created the metabox:

```
add_meta_box('custom-meta-box', 'Music', 'music_meta_box', 'clinica', 'advanced', 'core');
```

Used the code suggested, but I'm getting the error:

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in
>   C:\wamp\www\dwa\wp-content\plugins\network-cliniche\network-cliniche.php
>   on line 86

What am I doing wrong?

---

I add $callback_args but i still receive same error message.

Here is my code:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'network_cliniche_register_post_type' );

    function network_cliniche_register_post_type() {
        $cliniche_args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => 'clinica',
            'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'clinica',
            'with_front' => false
            ),

            'description' => 'Elenco cliniche appartenti al network',
            'has_archive' => 'true',
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'clinica_tax' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-networking',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Cliniche',
                'singular_name' => 'Clinica',
                'all_items' => 'Tutte le cliniche',
                'add_new' => 'Aggiungi clinica ',
                'add_new_item' => 'Aggiungi clinica',
                'edit_item' => 'Modifica clinica',
                'new_item' => 'Nuova clinica',
                'view_item' => 'Visualizza clinica',
                'search_items' => 'Cerca cliniche',
                'not_found' => 'Nessuna clinica registrata',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Non sono presenti cliniche nel cestino'
        ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_clinica_metaboxes'
        );

        register_post_type( 'clinica', $cliniche_args );

        function add_clinica_metaboxes() {
add_meta_box('dettagli-clinica', 'Dettagli clinica', 'dettagli_clinica', 'clinica', 'advanced', 'core');
            add_meta_box('custom-meta-box', 'Music clinica', 'music_meta_box', 'clinica', 'advanced', 'core', $callback_args);
        }
    }
```

metabox from :[How to save multiple checkbox on update post meta in wordpress?](http://How%20to%20save%20multiple%20checkbox%20on%20update%20post%20meta%20in%20wordpress?)

```
function music_meta_box()
{
global $post;
    // Get post meta value using the key from our save function in the second paramater.
$custom_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);

    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="huge" <?php echo (in_array('huge', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Huge
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="house" <?php echo (in_array('house', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />House
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="custom-meta-box[]" value="techno" <?php echo (in_array('techno', $custom_meta)) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Techno<br>
    <?php 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_music_meta_box' );


function save_music_meta_box()
{

    global $post;
    // Get our form field
    if(isset( $_POST['custom-meta-box'] ))
    {
        $custom = $_POST['custom-meta-box'];
        $old_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', true);
        // Update post meta
        if(!empty($old_meta)){
            update_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom);
        } else {
            add_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom-meta-box', $custom, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, putting some code that we can see what you coded would help a lot ;)

Comment: you have missed `$callback_args` .

Comment: what should I put instead of  $callback_args?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_meta_box('custom-meta-box', 'Music', 'music_meta_box', 'clinica', 'advanced', 'core');
```

should be

```
add_meta_box('custom-meta-box', 'Music', 'music_meta_box', 'clinica', 'advanced', 'core', $callback_args);
```

where `$callback_args` can be a function having return type array or an array itself.

see [codex for add_meta_box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)